# Will WD-40 dissolve plastic?

Tags: plastic, lubrication, dissolve

I've seen cases where it has harmed certain metals. Will plastic dissolve in prolonged exposure to WD-40?

Comment: http://wd40.com

Comment: According to the link @mike posted, WD-40 is safe for metals and plastics. What metals have you seen harmed by it? And what kind of prolonged exposure are you talking about?

Comment: Exposure as in, say, leaving it there until it dries out and I've seen sites that say that for metals, it attracts rust in door frames and other things, also, I don't know if it was safe for use with weak plastic, always good to be sure.

Comment: Ironically, WD40 was invented to prevent rust. WD stands for Water Displacement. It shouldn't "attract rust"

Comment: @superpatosainz WD40 will displace water. However, WD40 is not designed to stick around for the long term and provide ongoing protection. Once the WD40 has done its job, then you need to replace it with something else to prevent future water intrusion. This is why there is the perception that WD40 "causes" rust. Even if water intrusion is not the problem, you still need to put something in for lubrication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(since most people answered in the comments.)

No, it won't.